# f:ajax onerror called before listener

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, jsf-2, mojarra

I have a simple form and a pretty simple bean that listens to an ajax event. Here is some of the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myfunction() {
         alert('error');
    }
</script>
<h:commandButton  id="someid" value="somevalue" >
   <f:ajax event="click" execute="someids" listener="#{MyBean.fireEvent}" onerror="myfunction()"  />    
</h:commandButton>
```

I am using eclipse in debug to see when `MyBean.fireEvent` is getting called and as far as I can tell it is getting called after `onerror="myfunction()"` is executed. What could be the reason for that?

I am using mojarra 2.0 with Resin.

Thanks.

Comment: Figured out how to get it to work. Above the `myfunction()` definition I added `jsf.ajax.addOnError(myfunction);` and removed the `onerror="myfunction()"` attribute from the ajax tag. I am still curious as to why the onerror attribute didn't work though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

looks like a formatting problem, maybe try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function myfunction(error) {
     alert(error.description);
  }
</script>

<h:commandButton  id="someid" value="somevalue" >
  <f:ajax event="click" 
       execute="someids" 
       listener="#{MyBean.fireEvent}" 
       onerror="myfunction" />    
</h:commandButton>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `onerror` attribute must point to the function name itself, not to the return value of the function.

So, if you replace

```
onerror="myfunction()"
```

by

```
onerror="myfunction"
```

then it should work as expected.